# What is the type of "auto var = {condition} ? 1 : 1.0" in C++11? Is it double or int?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, auto, ternary-operator

In C++11 what are the types of `x` and `y` when I write this?

```
int main()
{
    auto x = true ? 1 : 1.0;
    auto y = false ? 1 : 1.0;
    std::cout << x << endl;
    std::cout << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template<class>struct typeof;template struct typeof<std::common_type_t<int,double>>;`

Comment: You can use [typeid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4158dbd29785207) for that (also i think boost has its own typeid like thing)

Comment: It's the common type of `int` and `double`, so `double`.

Comment: For novices) 1) the type (auto) should be determined in compile-time, not run-time. 2) `int` and `double` have 'common type' so the type is determined to be `double`, regardless of the condition in the conditional(ternary) operator. But let's think about `auto x = true? 1: "1"` - this doesn't compile since there is no common type between `int` and `const char*` and the type must be determined in compile-time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type is going to be `double`, because it's the [common type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/common_type/) of the literals `1` and `1.0`.

There's a simple way to test that using `typeid` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto x = true ? 1 : 1.0;
    cout << typeid(x).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `d` on my version of GCC.
Running `echo d | c++filt -t` then tells us that `d` corresponds to the type `double`, as expected.

Comment: [Another useful C++ resource here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) claims `common_type` to be defined in terms of what the `? :` operator produces.

Answer (score 5):

According to the description of the conditional operator in the C++ Standard (5.16 Conditional operator)

> 6 Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>   function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the
>   second and third operands. After those conversions, one of the
>   following shall hold:
>
> — The second and third operands have arithmetic or enumeration type;
>   **the usual arithmetic conversions are performed** to bring them to a common type, and the result is of that type.

And (5 Expressions)

> 10 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. **This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions**,
>   which are defined as follows:
>
> — Otherwise, **if either operand is double, the other shall be converted
>   to double.**

In the both usages of the conditional operator one of operands is floating literal having type double - `1.0` (the C++Standard: The type of a floating literal is **double** unless explicitly specified by a suffix.)

```
auto x = true ? 1 : 1.0;
auto y = false ? 1 : 1.0;
```

So the other operand also will be converted to type double and the result of expressions has type double.