# How to infer the type of the function that can return type depending on condition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, casting

I have a template function that takes two data types - int and double and returns the one which is smaller, Now, How can I infer the type that will be returned by this function? Right now, I am losing the parts after the decimal points.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class First, class Second>
First smaller(First a, Second b){
   return (a < b ? a : b);
}

int main () {
   int x = 100;
   double y = 15.5;
   cout<< smaller (x,y) << endl;

}
```

Comment: Do you want the return type to depend on which input is smaller, or do you want it to look at the input types of int and double and decide that double is the best output type? C++ is statically typed, so the return type can't depend on the input values.

Comment: If you are trying to decide on the return type of the function based on the inputs, that is not possible in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard behaviour of the ternary operator is to perform 'usual arithmetic conversions'. The means promoting the `int` to a `double` in this case.
That's the same as in `auto x=1/1.0;` is a `double` because of promotion of the integer numerator to be compatible with the `double` denominator.

See the answers to [What is the type of "auto var = {condition} ? 1 : 1.0" in C++11? Is it double or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886226/what-is-the-type-of-auto-var-condition-1-1-0-in-c11-is-it-double-or).
There are 'laymans terms' and standards quote answers. Both should help.

However what you've done is force the type to be `First':

```
template <class First, class Second>
First smaller(First a, Second b){
   return (a < b ? a : b);
}
```

Look at the return type you put in for `smaller`.
So what is happening is it's being promoted to a `double` and then converted to an `int` return value.

Take a look at this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class First, class Second>
First smaller(First a, Second b){
   return (a < b ? a : b);
}


template <class First, class Second>
auto smaller_auto(First a, Second b){
   return (a < b ? a : b);
}


int main() {
    int x=100;
    double y=15.5;

    std::cout<< smaller(x,y)<<std::endl; //First is int returns an int.

    std::cout<< smaller(y,x)<<std::endl;//First is double returns double.


    std::cout<< smaller_auto(x,y)<<std::endl; //Performs the usual arithemtic conversions (returns double).

    std::cout<< smaller_auto(y,x)<<std::endl;//Performs the usual arithemtic conversions (returns double).

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
15
15.5
15.5
15.5
```

Comment: You've described the _problem_ but not the _solution_, which is to declare the return type as `std::common_type<First, Second>::type`. Simply using `auto` as you've shown is a solution, but only for C++14, and this question is tagged `c++11`.

Comment: @ildjarn Fair point. I should also have pointed out that the 'real' right answer is to use `std::min<>()`.